# Adding class to Post body only with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a plugin called ACF to add custom fields to WordPress. I have enabled a class 'dark' to be added to some posts within their body tags if the option is checked.

```
   function add_acf_body_class( $classes ) {
       global $post;
       $value = get_field( 'dark_mode' );
       if ( $value ) {
           $classes[] = 'dark'; 
       }
       return $classes;
   }
   add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_acf_body_class' );
```

The function is working fine and only adds the class within selected posts' body tags except when I set up the index.php page. For some weird reason, it is adding this class to the index.php body tag though there's no option to do so, and the custom fields rule is only applied to posts only.

Is there a way I can be more precise in calling this function to post only I have tried every possible combination within ACF but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It's difficult to say why this might be happening. However, one possible solution is to modify the function to only add the dark class to the body tag of posts, and not to the body tag of any other pages. Here's an example.  
`function add_acf_body_class( $classes ) {  
global $post;
    
    // Check if we're on a single post
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $value = get_field( 'dark_mode', $post->ID );
        if ( $value ) {
            $classes[] = 'dark'; 
        }
    }
    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_acf_body_class' );`

Comment: @Irfan Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. is_single() / is_singular is what was lacking in my script. It is now sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the add_acf_body_class() function is being called on the index.php page because it is also considered a post type in WordPress. To apply this function only to specific post types, you can add a conditional statement that checks for the current post type before adding the 'dark' class.

Here's an updated version of the code that should work for posts only:

```
function add_acf_body_class( $classes ) {
   global $post;
   if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) { // Only apply to single posts
      $value = get_field( 'dark_mode' );
      if ( $value ) {
         $classes[] = 'dark'; 
      }
   }
   return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_acf_body_class' );
```

The is_singular() function checks whether the current page is a singular post type (such as a single post, page or attachment). In this case, we're checking specifically for the 'post' post type. This way, the 'dark' class will only be added to the body tag on single post pages, and not on other pages like the index.php page.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Totally agree. The is_singular( 'post' ) is what I was missing. Thank you very much it worked flawlessly.